# How to fix issues when install phpmyadmin with php7 on centos7

Tags: php7

How to install phpmyadmin. `yum install phpmyadmin` and it display error

Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using php5.4 earlier and upgraded to php7,
so the packages are causing conflict.

Try using `yum remove <package_name>` , try to remove any of them and it should work.

Comment: That doesn't work for me in the same situation, I have no php 5.4 packages installed...